# ¿Este código está hecho de la manera correcta?

Tags: c++, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles

Buenas tardes soy nueva en programación y estoy aprendiendo sobre bucles. He hecho un código donde la idea era con el uso de los bucles crear un juego de ahorcados en c++, pero no estoy segura se la manera en la que lo hice es muy correcta o la mejor. Por eso quisiera saber si el siguiente código si esta hecho de la manera correcta:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()


{
    
    int i, vidas=3; 
    string palabra;
    
    cout << "********************************************Juego Ahorcados********************************************"<<endl;
    cout <<endl << "Bienvenido a ahorcados, este juego está compuesto de una serie de adivinanzas donde la respuesta es una" <<endl <<"palabra y tu tienes que adivinarla."<<endl<<"Solo tienes 3 vidas, si se acaban antes de adivinar la palabra habrás perdido"<<endl;
    
    cout <<endl <<"Partida I" <<endl;
    
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
     {
        
    cout <<endl << "Instrumento que mide la densidad de los aceites: " <<endl;
    cout<<"Ingresa la palabra: ";
    cin>>palabra;
    
    if(palabra=="Oleometro")
    {
    cout<<endl<<"¡Respuesta correcta!" <<endl;
    
    cout <<endl <<"Partida II" <<endl;
    
     for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
     {  
    
    cout <<endl << "Técnica que describe y representa detalladamente la superficie de un terreno: " <<endl;
    cout<<"Ingresa la palabra: ";
    cin>>palabra;
    
    if(palabra=="Topografía")
    {
        
    cout<<endl<<"¡Respuesta correcta!" <<endl;
    
    cout <<endl <<"Partida III" <<endl;
    
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
     {  
    cout <<endl << "Material con el que Miguel Angel esculpió «La Piedad» ubicada en el Vaticano: " <<endl;
    cout<<"Ingresa la palabra: ";
    cin>>palabra;
    
    if(palabra=="Marmol")
    {
        
    cout<<endl<<"¡Respuesta correcta!" <<endl;
    
    cout<<endl<<"¡Felicidades! Ha ganado el juego";
    
    return 0;
    
    }
    else
    {  cout<<endl<<"¡Respuesta incorrecta!" <<endl;
      
         if(vidas==1)
        { 
            vidas--;
            cout <<endl<< "Vidas restantes: " <<vidas;
            cout <<endl<< "Lamentablemente tus vidas se han agotado, has pérdido el juego.";
            return 0; }
        vidas --;
        cout <<endl<<"Vidas restantes: " <<vidas <<endl;
    }
     }
    }
    else
    {  cout<<endl<<"¡Respuesta incorrecta!" <<endl;
      
         if(vidas==1)
        { 
            vidas--;
            cout <<endl<< "Vidas restantes: " <<vidas;
            cout <<endl<< "Lamentablemente tus vidas se han agotado, has pérdido el juego.";
            return 0; }
        vidas --;
        cout <<endl<<"Vidas restantes: " <<vidas <<endl;
    }
     }
    }
    else
    {  cout<<endl<<"¡Respuesta incorrecta!"<<endl;
      
         if(vidas==1)
        { 
            vidas--;
            cout <<endl<< "Vidas restantes: " <<vidas;
            cout <<endl<< "Lamentablemente tus vidas se han agotado, has pérdido el juego.";
            return 0; }
        vidas --;
        cout <<endl<<"Vidas restantes: " <<vidas<<endl;
    }
     }
         
    

    return 0;
}
```

Quiero agregar que soy estudiante, apenas estoy iniciando a aprender sobre c++ y programación en general agradecería que fueran lo más sincer@S y respetuos@s posible, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta no se termina de ajustar del todo (*pues luce basada en opiniones*) recomiendo leas [ask] y cheques https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ahora está mejor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tiene tu código es que es poco escalable ... es relativamente complicado corregir, añadir y eliminar respuestas. Quizás ahora mismo no, pero si siguieses añadiendo preguntas el programa se volvería inmanejable.

Piensa por ejemplo que te piden cambiar el formato de la pregunta ... o el texto de cuand el usuario se ha equivocado, ¿vas a ir pregunta por pregunta actualizando todo el programa?

Sería preferible almacenar las preguntas y sus respuestas en una estructura. Por ejemplo:

```
struct Tarjeta
{
    std::string pregunta;
    std::string respuesta;
};

std::vector<Tarjeta> tarjetas= {
    { "Instrumento que mide la densidad de los aceites", "oleometro" },
    { "Técnica que describe y representa detalladamente la superficie de un terreno", "Topografia" },
    // ...
};

int vidas=3;

for (auto const& tarjeta: tarjetas)
{
    bool acertada = false;
    for (int i=0; i<vidas && !acertada; i++)
    {
        std::cout << tarjeta.pregunta<< ":\n";
        std::string respuesta;
        std::cin >> respuesta;

        if (respuesta==tarjeta.respuesta)
            acertada = true;
        else
            std::cout << "Respuesta incorrecta!!!\n"
                      << "Vidas restantes: " << vidas << '\n';
    }

    if (!acertada) break;
}
```

Este diseño te aporta una gran flexibilidad:

- Facil de mantener: el programa no crece por muchas preguntas que le pongas
- Facil de actualizar: todas las preguntas se gestionan con el mismo bucle
- Podrías meter las preguntas en un archivo de texto o base de datos en vez de en el programa
- Podrías mostrar las preguntas en orden aleatorio

En otro orden de cosas:

**No abuses de `std::endl`**

`std::endl` no solo añade un salto de línea sino que fuerza al vaciado del buffer.

El vaciado del buffer representa una tarea del Sistema Operativo. Cada vez que el buffer se vacía se realiza una petición al SO y ese tipo de peticiones son bastante costosas (por eso se usan buffers).

Por otro lado esta tarea ya se realiza de forma automática, lo que nos permite despreocuparnos el 99% de las veces.

Únicamente en unos pocos casos contados está justificado el vaciado de un buffer. En el resto de las situaciones lo deseable es dejar al sistema elegir el mejor momento para realizar esta operación.

**Cuidado con los números mágicos**

```
for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
```

Este bucle se repite 3 veces en tu programa, una vez por cada pregunta. Ese 3 se considera un número mágico, por que ¿De dónde viene ese número? ¿Por qué 3 exactamente? ¿Qué pasaría si ponemos cualquier otro valor?

Esas son preguntas típicas que se podría hacer alguien que revisase tu código, por ejemplo buscando un error.

Los números mágicos hay que intentar evitarlos ya que suelen ser fuente de errores, sobretodo si el número mágico se usa en varias partes del código.

Es preferible usar una constante:

```
// Hasta C++03
const int MaxIntentos=3;

// C++11 en adelante
constexpr int MaxIntentos=3;
```

Quedando el bucle:

```
for (int i=0; i<MaxIntentos; i++)
```